# How to attach to an MDF database file using OLEDB in C++?

Tags: c++, sql-server, oledb

My C++ code successfully restores an SqlServer database backup file and then extracts the necessary information from the resulting database using the OLEDB API.

Here is my C++ code, in the end of which I get an `IDBCreateCommand` instance ready to be used for executing various queries against the restored database:

```
DB::DB(LPCWSTR wszDataSource, LPCWSTR wszBackupFilePath, LPCWSTR wszRestoreFolderPath)
{
  fs::path backupFilePath = fs::canonical(wszBackupFilePath).make_preferred();
  fs::path restoreFolderPath = fs::canonical(wszRestoreFolderPath).make_preferred();
  std::wstring db = backupFilePath.leaf().stem().wstring();
  boost::wformat restoreQueryFmt(L"RESTORE DATABASE [%2%] FROM DISK = N'%1%' WITH REPLACE, STATS = 10, MOVE N'%2%' TO N'%3%\\%2%.mdf', MOVE N'%2%_log' TO N'%3%\\%2%.LDF'");
  std::wstring query = (restoreQueryFmt % backupFilePath.wstring() % db % restoreFolderPath.wstring()).str();

  IDBInitializePtr spDBInitialize;
  HRESULT hr = spDBInitialize.CreateInstance(CLSID_SQLNCLI10, NULL);
  if (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG == hr)
  {
    hr = spDBInitialize.CreateInstance(CLSID_SQLNCLI, NULL);
  }
  _HRESULT_CHECK3(spDBInitialize, hr);

  _variant_t vDataSource(wszDataSource);
  _variant_t vAuth(L"SSPI");

  DBPROP dbprop[2];          // property used in property set to initialize provider

  dbprop[0].dwPropertyID = DBPROP_INIT_DATASOURCE;
  dbprop[0].dwOptions  = DBPROPOPTIONS_REQUIRED;
  dbprop[0].vValue = vDataSource;

  dbprop[1].dwPropertyID  = DBPROP_AUTH_INTEGRATED;
  dbprop[1].dwOptions = DBPROPOPTIONS_REQUIRED;
  dbprop[1].vValue = vAuth;

  DBPROPSET dbpropset[1];        // Property Set used to initialize provider
  dbpropset[0].guidPropertySet = DBPROPSET_DBINIT;
  dbpropset[0].rgProperties  = dbprop;
  dbpropset[0].cProperties = sizeof(dbprop)/sizeof(dbprop[0]);

   // Set initialization properties.
  IDBPropertiesPtr spDBProperties = spDBInitialize;

  _HRESULT_CHECK(spDBProperties, SetProperties(1, dbpropset));
  _HRESULT_CHECK(spDBInitialize, Initialize());

  IDBCreateSessionPtr spCreateSession = spDBInitialize;
  _HRESULT_CHECK(spCreateSession, CreateSession(NULL, IID_IDBCreateCommand, reinterpret_cast<IUnknown **>(&m_spDBCreateCommand)));

  ICommandTextPtr spCommandText;
  _HRESULT_CHECK(m_spDBCreateCommand, CreateCommand(NULL, IID_ICommandText, reinterpret_cast<IUnknown **>(&spCommandText)));

  _HRESULT_CHECK(spCommandText, SetCommandText(DBGUID_SQL, query.c_str()));
  _HRESULT_CHECK(spCommandText, Execute(NULL, IID_NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL));
  _HRESULT_CHECK(spCommandText, SetCommandText(DBGUID_SQL, (boost::wformat(L"USE \"%1%\"") % db).str().c_str()));
  _HRESULT_CHECK(spCommandText, Execute(NULL, IID_NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL));
}
```

What it does is:

1. Initializes a new database connection using the given data source (like ".\SQLEXPRESS") and SSPI integrated authentication scheme.
2. Executes a `RESTORE DATABASE` T-SQL statement, like this one: `RESTORE DATABASE [my_db] FROM DISK = N'c:\temp\my_db.ebf' WITH REPLACE, STATS = 10, MOVE 'my_db' TO N'c:\temp\my_db.mdf', MOVE N'my_db_log' TO N'c:\temp\my_db.LDF'`
3. Use the new database for the subsequent queries by running `USE "my_db"`

So, I have no problems restoring a database backup file and proceding from there.

Now I am facing another problem. Suppose there is no backup file, rather an already existing MDF file - how do I attach to it using the OLEDB C++ API?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

It is assumed that the .mdf file is accompanied by all the files required by the database engine - .ldf and others as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot attach a database if all you have is and MDF file because that is, at best, only half of the database. You need an MD **and an LDF**. And any additional NDF or secondary LDF files that composed the original database.

Suppose you have the MDF and the LDF as %1% and %3%, then all you have to do is execute this statement:

```
CREATE DATABASE [%2%] 
  ON (FILENAME=N'%1%')
  , (FILENAME=N'%3')
  FOR ATTACH;
```

See [How to: Move a Database Using Detach and Attach (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187858.aspx)

The option to attach and MDF alone does exists (use `FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG`) but it comes with many warnings, as it only works on a cleanly shut down database (it can lead to a corrupted database otherwise). There is no option to attach a database if you're missing secondary NDF files.

Comment: btw, have you considered using Managed C++ and [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx), or mix in a managed DLL that leverages SMO and exposes the needed functionality to your app via COM?

Comment: My app has to deal with three db engines, one of which is embedded mysql (libmysqld.dll) server, for which there is no managed wrapper. Hence I decided to stay in native C++ all the way.